# How do I save a file stream straight to an excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, stream

To give you a bit of context I'm trying to download a bunch of attachments in one bulk operation. These attachments are normally downloaded via a website a file at a time and the MVC controller code which retrieves the attachment looks something like this:

```
    var attachment = _attachmentsRepository.GetAttachment(websiteId, id);
    if (attachment.FileStream == null || !attachment.FileStream.CanRead)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

     var content = new StreamContent(attachment.FileStream);
     content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = $"{id}.{attachment.Extension}" };

     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = content };
```

What I'm trying to do is write a console application for the bulk operation which will save each file directly to disk and sofar what I've got for a single file save is:

```
        var = attachment attachmentsRepository.GetAttachment(websiteId, resource.Id);
        attachment.FileStream.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(attachment.FileStream);
        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        File.WriteAllText(someFilePath, content);
```

I've side-stepped any http specific framework classes since I just need to download directly to file via code instead of the browser. This code successfully generates files but when I open them Excel indicates that they're corrupted which I suspect is an encoding issue. I'm currently playing around with the encoding at the moment but sofar not much luck so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Excel is binary and you should never use text/string methods with binary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `StreamReader` for processing binary data. The `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` classes are for reading and writing human-readable text in a `Stream` and as such they attempt to perform text encoding/decoding which can mangle binary data (I feel the classes should be renamed to `StreamTextReader`/`StreamTextWriter` to reflect their inheritance hierarchy).

To read raw binary data, use methods on the `Stream` class directly (e.g. `Read`, `Write`, and `CopyTo`).

Try this:

```
var attachment = ...
using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( someFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 8 * 1024, useAsync: true ) )
{
    await attachment.FileStream.CopyToAsync( fs );
}
```

The `using()` block will ensure `fs` is flushed and closed correctly.